# Html entity decode issue using html2pdf

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8, fpdf, html2pdf

I'm trying to display strings of text fetched from a database in a PDF document correctly. What I can't figure out is the following.

I'm using fpdf and html2pdf for the generation of the PDF document. After I fetched my information from my DB I use:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $data);
```

This displays correctly in the PDF document if I use:

```
$pdf->Cell();
```

But when I use:

```
$pdf->WriteHtmlCell();
```

it seems that it has decoding issues. It seems to be in another charset because ù turns into Ã¹ and Ä into Ã„ and so on. I have tried to convert it to UTF-8 (which it is originally in) or ISO, but I keep getting the same result. When I run a

```
mb_detect_encoding();
```

on the string it always comes back as ASCII (that is UTF-8?).

Is `WriteHtmlCell();` using another encoding?

Comment: Well you can see the detect encoding part is correct: that ù decodes to UTF8 `c3 b9`, or as 2 characters in Latin1 encoding [A tilde](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c3/index.htm) + [superscript 1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b9/index.htm). Does your new HTML file state it's encoded in UTF8?

Comment: @RadLexus Yes the charset meta of the page is: <meta charset="utf-8">. I think that it has somthing to do with the html2pdf extension of fpdf. Or am I mistaking?

Comment: Does anybody know where i can look for an solution? I tried encoding before the output but that doesnt work.

Comment: It helps if you [edit] your post and add what you tried and why it did not work. Editing your post also bumps it back up to the front page so it may attract more views.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
html_entity_decode($your_data, ENT_XHTML,"ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Thanks! I change my content before write to PDF and it work:
$content = html_entity_decode($content, ENT_XHTML,"utf-8");